# Totally replace the Android frontend UI by a special purpose device UI

Tags: android

Suppose, someone wants to replace the default frontend of an Android device by a new custom one. Once which provides certain functionality by means of a special purpose application - but not even a bit of any other Android application.

In other words: How to convert an Android device into a special purpose device.

I wonder, if this is an approach, for which the Android SDK provides options.

It is possible? How to reach this goal? Please provide technical insights.

**Edit and reply @CommonsWare:**

I don't want to have a Linux OS with some UI, but a standard device, which provides the standard Android SDK, since the SDK's API is well suited for touch based applications. Additionally, Android SDK is well know by many developers.

A way to have a single user-space app control the device, as if this app would be the only app, would be fine too.

E.g. Apple provides ways to shrink fit iOS (in certain ways): Disable apps, hide controls or disable mobile radio.

Comment: I don't know how well this fits into stackoverflow (my suspicion is that it doesn't) but you'd want to look at making your own custom build with the Android source code. This is the same stuff that device makers work with.

Comment: Close? Why? This is a purely software related question. OK, a special one.

Comment: This is actually a good question.  Android is growing in availability of devices and programmers, and it can make sense to use it as a starting point for a custom special-purpose device.  Consider that's what the B&N Nook, Google TV, etc are - something custom and limiting on the front, android underneath.

Comment: Exactly! That's what I ask for. A special purpose device for a special market.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you want to keep the android runtime & UI libraries to use as your building blocks, I think you would start by implementing your all in one application as a replacement home screen launcher.

You can test all of the feature-functionality of this on an unmodified, unrooted device - however anyone can go into settings and reselect the original launcher.

To deploy in a secured form you would need to modify an android build - remove the option to de-select your app, possibly disable adb (tradeoff vs. serviceability), remove any application markets, remove all of the Google account services and setup wizard, etc.

Comment: That's what I expected. Thank you! I'll keep the question open. Hopefully, others answer.

Comment: Add-on question: Could you clarify, if the device-dependent code and the device-independent code are separated against each other? My e.g. device a standard tablet and replace patch, build and replace the device-independet code only?

Comment: I think that depends on the vendor tree you start with - as may how hard it is to even collect all the sources needed to make a custom build approximating what the device shipped with.  If you are selecting hardware vendors, this would be a thing to take into account.  If you have unsecured devices, it might be possible to do your install as an update.zip which does not wipe the factory install, but only adds/changes a few things.

Answer (score 0):

> Suppose, someone wants to replace the default frontend of an Android device by a new custom one.

Android is pretty much exclusively "frontend". What you are therefore saying is that you want Android without all the Android in it. Or, if this were a restaurant, you would be placing an order for a plate of Android, but please hold the Android.

> In other words: How to convert an Android device into a special purpose device.

If you want embedded Linux and your own UI, use embedded Linux and your own UI.

What do you expect Android to do for you here that you cannot more readily solve with another embedded Linux distro?

> I wonder, if this is an approach, for which the Android SDK provides options.

Not really, since the Android SDK is pretty much entirely devoted to "frontend".